# 3 Root accounts in MySQl database

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, root

I have managed to get mySQL running under Ubuntu 8.10, I am now diligently trying to secure the database and am adding passwords for the root users.

My question:

I have a root user under the host "kickseed" with no password set

I have no idea what kickseed is as the database is installed under localhost, on searching around i have discovered that this is something to do with the ubuntu OS itself.

Is it safe to delete this user account from MySQL or is it used for something by the OS?

If i need to keep it should i /can i protect it with a password?

Also i have another root account under the host IP 127.0.0.1 again can i delete this?

My absolute preference would be to have only one account with root access but i do not want to delete these accounts if they are necessary.

Thanks for tolerating a newbie

Regards

Hairby

Comment: kickseed is ubuntu/debian alternative to kickstart. that's as much as i know about it i'm afraid. not sure about it's internals, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recognize kickseed as being anything standard, but it might be something that a program is using from a host on your network.  I would start by checking whether the name resolves on your network and whether it is in the hosts file on the DB server.  If it does or is, track down the machine and figure out why it is connecting to the database and see if you can switch it to a non root account, or at least what you have to do to password protect it.  If you can't find the machine, I would password protect the account and wait a while to see if anything breaks, if it doesn't then it is probably safe to delete the account.  127.0.0.1 is your loopback address, deleting that one is probably bad news.

Comment: Agreed. Leave the localhost entry, and make sure that MySQL is running on 127.0.0.1, which will prevent other hosts from connecting with _any_ account.